# How to Iterate lists of named tuples, filter and group by key values then process for output

Tags: python, list, tuples, nested-loops, python-itertools

How do I get the desired output below from these 3 lists of named tuples?

```
drumlist = [drums( title='99_drumtrack_1.wav', bpm='99'),
drums( title='95_drumtrack_2.wav', bpm='95'),
drums( title='93_drumtrack_3.wav', bpm='93'),
#etc...
]

melodylist = [melody( title='99_Abmin_melodytrack_1.wav', bpm='99', key='Abmin'),
melody( title='95_Bbmin_melodytrack_2.wav', bpm='95' ,key='Bbmin'),
melody(title='93_Fmaj_melodytrack_3.wav', bpm='93' , key='Fmaj'),
melody(title='92_Gmaj_melodytrack_4.wav', bpm='92' , key='Gmaj')
#etc...
]

basslist = [bass( title='99_Abmin_basstrack_1.wav', bpm='99', key='Abmin'),
bass(title='95_Bbmin_basstrack_2.wav', bpm='95', key='Bbmin'),
bass(title='93_Fmaj_basstrack_3.wav', bpm='93', key='Fmaj')
#etc...
]
```

#My desired output:

```
#interation 1
sound1 = 99_drumtrack_1.wav
sound2 = 99_Abmin_melodytrack_1.wav #KEYNOTE Abmin key for melody matches Abmin key for bass
sound3 = 99_Abmin_basstrack_1.wav #KEYNOTE Abmin key for bass matches Abmin key for melody
#use sound1, sound2 & sound3 variables further

#interation 2
sound1 = 95_drumtrack_2.wav
sound2 = 95_Bbmin_melodytrack_2.wav
sound3 = 95_Bbmin_basstrack_2.wav
#use sound1, sound2 & sound3 variables further

#etc...
```

I am using sound1,2,3 to do further processing , [I use a nested for loop in my script](https://pastebin.com/Sb8Xqqig) to iterate through one big list instead of three, which is working crudely, but I am using too many indentations, and I am stuck on how to make my approach more efficient.

I am aware itertools may help ,but am not skilled enough to implement. I was also advised that I do not need a generator in this scenario as the lists are finite.

Comment: `for sound1, sound2, sound3 in zip(drumlist, melodylist, basslist):`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this

```
for i, element in enumerate(zip(drumlist, melodylist, basslist)):
    sound1, sound2, sound3 = element
    keynote = f" #KEYNOTE {sound2.key} key for melody matches {sound3.key} key for bass" if sound2.key == sound3.key else ''
    print(f"interation {i+1}")
    print(f"sound1 = {sound1.title}")
    print(f"sound2 = {sound2.title}{keynote}")
    print(f"sound3 = {sound3.title}{keynote}")
    print()
```

output

```
interation 1
sound1 = 99_drumtrack_1.wav
sound2 = 99_Abmin_melodytrack_1.wav #KEYNOTE Abmin key for melody matches Abmin key for bass
sound3 = 99_Abmin_basstrack_1.wav #KEYNOTE Abmin key for melody matches Abmin key for bass

interation 2
sound1 = 95_drumtrack_2.wav
sound2 = 95_Bbmin_melodytrack_2.wav #KEYNOTE Bbmin key for melody matches Bbmin key for bass
sound3 = 95_Bbmin_basstrack_2.wav #KEYNOTE Bbmin key for melody matches Bbmin key for bass

interation 3
sound1 = 93_drumtrack_3.wav
sound2 = 93_Fmaj_melodytrack_3.wav #KEYNOTE Fmaj key for melody matches Fmaj key for bass
sound3 = 93_Fmaj_basstrack_3.wav #KEYNOTE Fmaj key for melody matches Fmaj key for bass
```

Comment: I don't need interation or #keynote printed , thats just part of the commentary.

Comment: @AndrewJackson, these elements were in the output section.
Easy to modify the code ro get rid of them.